# Using Dataset with "USA_State" Column to Create New Column Called "USA_Region"

Tags: r

My R data cleaning and manipulation skills are pretty lacking and I realize it could be a lot faster to just export something like this into Excel and then bring it back into R if I want to use ggplot to create visualizations ... however, I'm sure there is a relatively easy/elegant way to handle this.

I have a dataset that has a column with "USA_State" specifying what state for each row (most have a single state in the cell, but a few have multiple states listed fyi). I'd like to use these regions: Northeast, North Central, Southern, Western based on the following system: https://nifa.usda.gov/efnep-where-you-live-partner-websites

Is there an easy way to make a new column called "USA_Region" that puts each row in these 4 regions based on the "USA_State" column? I assume I need to specify the states in each region (create a dataframe with the regions and each state in each region) and do something (maybe use mutate() )?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Make a data frame with two columns: USA_State and USA_Region.  Then use `dplyr::left_join()` to join it to your main data frame.

Comment: Ah ... my database/joining lack of experience shows. Let me try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A very easy solution is to start with the list of states (which you seem to already have), and then add a column that simply lists the USA_Region, like this:

```
states <- read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jasonong/List-of-US-States/master/states.csv', col_select = 'State')

states$USA_Region = c("Southern", "Western", "Western", "Southern", "Western", "Western", "Northeast", "Northeast", "Northeast", "Southern", "Southern", "Western", "Western", "North Central", "North Central", "North Central", "North Central", "Southern",
                  "Southern", "North Central", "Western", "Western", "Western", "Northeast", "Northeast", "Western", "Northeast", "Southern", "North Central", "North Central", "Southern", "Western", "Northeast", "Northeast",
                  "North Central", "North Central", "Southern", "North Central", "Northeast", "Northeast", "Southern", "North Central", "Southern", "Southern", "Western", "North Central", "Southern", "Western",
                  "Southern", "North Central", "Western")
```

Once you have that, do a simple check to make sure the listing is accurate:

```
states %>% 
  print(n = 51)
```

Then using dplyr verbs is a breeze. For example, finding all the states in the West is this:

```
west <- states %>% 
  filter(USA_Region == "Western")
```